# setwd() works weird inside a function?

Tags: r

I have a function for choosing files using `file.choose()`. When I call it inside a script I want it open certain directory where I wish to choose files. There is a cycle inside the function as I need to choose a bunch of files. First time it opens in the working directory, which is predictable. I put `setwd()` inside to make the needed directory as working directory so I can choose files there. But when dialog box opens next time it is again the old working directory. But next time it is the directory I need. If I choose different folders it works the same - next time the old directory but after that the new one. I wrote a short function that reproduces behavior:

```
foo <- function() {
  files <- NULL
  for (i in c(1,2,3,4,5)) {
    x <- file.choose()
    y <- dirname(x)
    setwd(y)
    print(y)
    print(getwd())
  }

}
```

Just call this function and try to choose files in different or same directories. You can see that directory name is new and `getwd()` says that new working directory is set but next file choice dialog opens in previous directory.
Please keep in mind that I need to use file.choose() function as it works on a headless OS, both Windows and Unix-like.
When I don't use `setwd()` it is always the old working directory.

Comment: It looks like that `file.choose` always list files from the directory in which the R session has started, regardless whether later you used `setwd` to change the working directory. This behaviour is not documented, due, maybe, to the not much common use of that function and its limited purpose.

Comment: Thank you @nicola for the answer but I have to say that `setwd()` works but in the second iteration of the `for` loop. Which is weird. I guess there is some variable somewhere that I can change right away not waiting for function to do it.